# How to join two tables to fetch common values

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I am just learning PHP. I have two tables one is table a and other is table b. Fields of table  a are:
 `snum, sfirst, smiddle, slast`. and Fields of table b are :
 `sr_no, st_id`. Here Table a's **snum** and table b's **st_id** have common values that is id of student. I want to join both tables and find out sfirst, smiddle, slast according to this id. I want to insert id in database and fetch names sfirst, smiddle, and slast according to st_id  of table b. Please guide me how can I solve it in easiest way?

Comment: "I am just learning PHP" --- how is it related to mysql-related question?

Comment: Learn about [SQL joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html).

Comment: @zerkms: people who are "just learning" LAMP development makes this common mistake as they relate everything together, which what actually happens, and they will learn that overtime ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have a look at the tutorials here

[Tutorials Point Mysql](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-using-joins.htm)

Please note that the above link takes you directly to the joins section :)

PS: [Tizag](http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/) also have some good Tutorials which are worth checking ;)

have a nice day :)

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT sfirst, smiddle, slast 
FROM tablea 
INNER JOIN tableb 
on tablea.snum = tableb.st_id 
WHERE tableb.st_id = 1
```